# Aggregates in DDD and Entity Framework

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

I have a question about what to do with a entity that is not a representation of the data in the database, but a custom made entity that I need for business purposes.

My solution is structured in:

- Entities assembly (POCO objects)
- Repository assembly (EF Code First)
- Business layer assembly
- UI Assembly (MVC)

In my entities assembly I have two entities, `A` and `B`, and for a specific purpose of my business logic, I need to return an object that contains both (among other properties):

```
class X
{
   public A[];
   public B[];
}
```

Should I return this object directly from the repository? Or should the business layer call to `repo.GetA` and `repo.GetB` and then create `X` and return it?

In this case, maybe it makes sense to create the object in the business layer. But what if the `X` class was a "group by" of `A` and `B`? then returning it from the repository makes more sense.

I guess there is no silver bullet, but are there any guidelines?

Cheers.

Comment: To follow true DDD I think that your Entities and Repository interfaces should all be in the Business (Domain) Layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to figure out which layer `X` belongs to and what it really is :

- A domain entity, i.e. it conveys a domain concept from the ubiquitous language. In that case, `X` is probably an aggregate root that contains a list of `A` and `B` child entities. It may also have methods in addition to data. `X`'s repository would persist the A and B collections along with `X` objects, and there would be no repository for `A` or `B`.
- A UI specific or use case specific data structure. In which case the domain layer has no business with `X`. The application or UI layer will take care of doing the mapping between `A` and `B` instances and the `X` object.

Comment: And what happens if  it is UI specific, but it is very expensive to create it out of the repository? E.g.: an entity result of a join/grouping of several tables?

Comment: You can have specialized "analytical" repositories besides the normal repositories. Similar problems are discussed here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098112/ddd-how-to-implement-high-performing-repositories-for-searching, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558469/ddd-aggregate-roots

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that the repository should always deal with business-type objects. For you this would be equivalent to a repository returning objects of type X. How X is created is the repository's business. This could be via 2 data mappers getting A and then B and merging the results or some other, appropriate, process.